# How to pass content of html with ajax (MVC)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to get HTML from the specific form and save it in HTML file that in my project.

So I have builder ajax function that is sending this HTML to the server and then I saving it.

I have a problem with send HTML to the server, if I send string `"Hello word"` , all working but with `"<p>Hello</p>"` it is not working.

What is the right way to send HTML content with ajax?

I know about     `[ValidateInput(false)]` but it is not working

This my controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
 [ValidateInput(false)]
 public void UpdateHtml(string html)
     {
        try
         {
             string path1 = @"D:\test\my.html";
             System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path1, html);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }

            }
```

This is my ajax:

```
function btn_Upload_Click() {

    var html = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();//my html
  //var html = "Hello"//Like this all working
    var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();//checked:OK
    var funcUrl = $("#btn_saveHtml").data("urlaction");//checked :OK
    $.ajax({
        url: funcUrl,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType : "text/xml",
        data: {
            html:html,
            __RequestVerificationToken: token
        },

        success: function (data)
        {
            alert("Good");
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {

            alert(xhr.responseText);
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(error);
        }
    });

}
```

Update2: My html that i am trying to send:

`"<p style=\"text-align: center; font-size: 15px;\"><img title=\"TinyMCE Logo\" src=\"//www.tinymce.com/images/glyph-tinymce@2x.png\" alt=\"TinyMCE Logo\" width=\"110\" height=\"97\" /></p>\n<h1 style=\"text-align: center;\">Welcome to the TinyMCE editor demo!</h1>\n<h1><img style=\"float: right; padding: 0 0 10px 10px;\" title=\"Tiny Husky\" src=\"//www.tinymce.com/docs/images/tiny-husky.jpg\" alt=\"Tiny Husky\" width=\"304\" height=\"320\" /></h1>\n<h2>Image Tools Plugin feature<br />Click on the image to get started</h2>\n<p>Please try out the features provided in this image tools example.</p>\n<p>Note that any <strong>MoxieManager</strong> file and image management functionality in this example is part of our commercial offering &ndash; the demo is to show the integration.</p>\n<h2>Got questions or need help?</h2>\n<ul>\n<li>Our <a href=\"https://www.tinymce.com/docs/\">documentation</a> is a great resource for learning how to configure TinyMCE.</li>\n<li>Have a specific question? Visit the <a href=\"http://community.tinymce.com/forum/\">Community Forum</a>.</li>\n<li>We also offer enterprise grade support as part of <a href=\"www.tinymce.com/pricing\">TinyMCE Enterprise</a>.</li>\n</ul>\n<h2>A simple table to play with</h2>\n<table>\n<thead>\n<tr>\n<th>Product</th>\n<th>Cost</th>\n<th>Really?</th>\n</tr>\n</thead>\n<tbody>\n<tr>\n<td>TinyMCE</td>\n<td>Free</td>\n<td>YES!</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Plupload</td>\n<td>Free</td>\n<td>YES!</td>\n</tr>\n</tbody>\n</table>\n<h2>Found a bug?</h2>\n<p>If you think you have found a bug please create an issue on the <a href=\"https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues\">GitHub repo</a> to report it to the developers.</p>\n<h2>Finally ...</h2>\n<p>Don't forget to check out our other product <a href=\"http://www.plupload.com\" target=\"_blank\">Plupload</a>, your ultimate upload solution featuring HTML5 upload support.</p>\n<p>Thanks for supporting TinyMCE! We hope it helps you and your users create great content.<br />All the best from the TinyMCE team.</p>"`

My ajax return empty error, so I can't get you more information.

Comment: __RequestVerificationToken can cause this.Did you use it like this in another request ? I mean sending as data the token not in header of request

Comment: Did you try this request without token ?

Comment: Yse i tried,like i write in the question if i send "Hello World" all works,the problem is in html that i am trying to send

Comment: Sorry i missed it. I have tried it i cannot explain why not working while sending only '<p>Hello</p>' because it works on my project.But with your html it is not working and then i have tried it with POST request not GET it works with your html.Did your try it with post request?

Comment: can you please post here you javascript and server side code?Maybe i am missing some think small

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is ajax request

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Test")',
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'text/xml',
        data: { "html": "<p style=\"text-align: center; font-size: 15px;\"><img title=\"TinyMCE Logo\" src=\"//www.tinymce.com/images/glyph-tinymce@2x.png\" alt=\"TinyMCE Logo\" width=\"110\" height=\"97\" /></p>\n<h1 style=\"text-align: center;\">Welcome to the TinyMCE editor demo!</h1>\n<h1><img style=\"float: right; padding: 0 0 10px 10px;\" title=\"Tiny Husky\" src=\"//www.tinymce.com/docs/images/tiny-husky.jpg\" alt=\"Tiny Husky\" width=\"304\" height=\"320\" /></h1>\n<h2>Image Tools Plugin feature<br />Click on the image to get started</h2>\n<p>Please try out the features provided in this image tools example.</p>\n<p>Note that any <strong>MoxieManager</strong> file and image management functionality in this example is part of our commercial offering &ndash; the demo is to show the integration.</p>\n<h2>Got questions or need help?</h2>\n<ul>\n<li>Our <a href=\"https://www.tinymce.com/docs/\">documentation</a> is a great resource for learning how to configure TinyMCE.</li>\n<li>Have a specific question? Visit the <a href=\"http://community.tinymce.com/forum/\">Community Forum</a>.</li>\n<li>We also offer enterprise grade support as part of <a href=\"www.tinymce.com/pricing\">TinyMCE Enterprise</a>.</li>\n</ul>\n<h2>A simple table to play with</h2>\n<table>\n<thead>\n<tr>\n<th>Product</th>\n<th>Cost</th>\n<th>Really?</th>\n</tr>\n</thead>\n<tbody>\n<tr>\n<td>TinyMCE</td>\n<td>Free</td>\n<td>YES!</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>Plupload</td>\n<td>Free</td>\n<td>YES!</td>\n</tr>\n</tbody>\n</table>\n<h2>Found a bug?</h2>\n<p>If you think you have found a bug please create an issue on the <a href=\"https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues\">GitHub repo</a> to report it to the developers.</p>\n<h2>Finally ...</h2>\n<p>Don't forget to check out our other product <a href=\"http://www.plupload.com\" target=\"_blank\">Plupload</a>, your ultimate upload solution featuring HTML5 upload support.</p>\n<p>Thanks for supporting TinyMCE! We hope it helps you and your users create great content.<br />All the best from the TinyMCE team.</p>" },
        error: function () {
            console.log("error");
        },
        success: function () {

        }
    })
```

And the server code

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public void Test(string html)
    {

    }
```

Of course i dont have any token.I can catch the html from server in debug mode.

Comment: I changed from get to post and all works,but i still don't understand why with data="Hello" works and with data "<p>Hello</p>"   not!?!?!?! I even dint used the Stringify the content to JSON........i am really confuse......any way i spend to many time on this problem thnks

Comment: I am confused too :)

Comment: Because your controller is a POST but you try to request it with GET

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the function

```
    html:encodeURIComponent(html);
```

See [Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this by multiple ways:-

1. **Stringify the content to JSON.**

   JSON.stringify({'html':HTML});
2. **Put your HTML string in single quotes.**

   ```
   [
       {
           "html": '<p>Hello World!</p>'
       }
   ];
   ```
3. **Escape your double quotes from your HTML code by adding "".**
4. **Use [Encoder.js](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jsool/source)**
   When data is passing use: `Encoder.htmlDecode(value);`

Also, while passing HTML in JSON remember [these](https://www.thorntech.com/4-things-you-must-do-when-putting-html-in-json/) 4 things.

Comment: And this is JSON.stringify({'html':HTML});  not  JSON.stringify({'html':html}) low case?Any way with low case it is not working too

Comment: Can you please share the HTML string that you are getting from tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()

Comment: I have used   var jsonString = JSON.stringify(strHtml); ,and i have updated my html you can see it in qustion,but it is still not working.